# When click multiple buttons it only shows one div

Tags: jquery, html, sass

I'm working on Dashboard UI and add code for some jquery function. I have multiple option buttons, and when I click multiple buttons it shows only one div.

HTML code:

```html
<button class="option-btn" id="optionBtn" title="Action">•••</button>
<div class="option-box" id="optionBox" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">View Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="deleteBtnSingle">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br><br>

<button class="option-btn" id="optionBtn" title="Action">•••</button>
<div class="option-box" id="optionBox" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">View Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="deleteBtnSingle">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br><br>

<button class="option-btn" id="optionBtn" title="Action">•••</button>
<div class="option-box" id="optionBox" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">View Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="deleteBtnSingle">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```js
$(function(){
   var $optionBtn = $('#optionBtn'),
       $optionBox = $('#optionBox');

    $($optionBtn).click(function(){
      if ($($optionBtn).on('cliked') + true) { 
         $(this).next().toggle();       
       } else {
          $(this).next().hide(); 
       }
    }); 

});
```

CSS:

```css
.option-btn {
   border: none;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: transparent;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: $contentColor;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font: 500 14px $fontStack;
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   outline: none;
   transition: all .2s;
   &:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 9px 0px #6680fe;
   }
   &:active {
      transform: translateY(1px);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px #6680fe;
   }
}


.option-box {
   background: $white;
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px $shadowColor;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 10px 0;
   width: 190px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 55px;
   right: 15px;
   transition: background .2s;
   transform-origin: 100% 0;
   animation: transform 100ms cubic-bezier(.27,.12,.41,.71);
   z-index: 5;


   ul {
      li {
         text-align: left;
         font: 300 14px $fontStack;
         vertical-align: middle;

         a {
            display: block;
            padding: 6px 20px;
            color: $contentColor;

            .option-icon {
               width: 19px;
               height: 19px;
               margin-right: 15px !important;
               position: relative;
               top: -1px;
            }

            &:hover {
               background: $selectHover;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used id selector to trigger the function.

The browser assumes id is unique in your code, so it selects the first one and ignores the rest.

try to select your divs by class. For example $('.option-button') instead of $('#optionBtn').